# Changed MySQL user password but scripts are still using the old password

Tags: php, mysql

I noticed a "weird" behavior with my PHP script. I used this MySQL command to change the password of a user:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'hostname' = PASSWORD('passwordhere');
```

The user above is what is given in php config files. I did not change this user's password in my php config file and I am still able to log into the website....which means that my webpages are still getting a DB connection (using the old password)!
How is this possible?

Point to note: I am able to log into phpMyAdmin ONLY using the new password!

Comment: If you mean you changed the password but a running process with a connection is still working, it is because the password is only used when the connection to the DB is first established.